# Golang Google alert XML parse

Tags: xml, go

My XML data :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
    xmlns:idx="urn:atom-extension:indexing">

    <entry>
        <title type="html">Some Title</title>
        <link href="https://www.google.com"></link>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

I want to parse Each `<entry>` with its `<title>`& `<link>` tag so far I have successfully parsed the title but no success with `<link>`.

My Code :

```
type Entry struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"entry"`
    Link    string   `xml:"link"`
    Title   string   `xml:"title"`
}

type Feed struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"feed"`
    Entries []Entry  `xml:"entry"`
}

func (s Entry) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("\t Link : %s - Title : %s \n", s.Link, s.Title)
}
```

Live demo at http://play.golang.org/p/hteQ5RuMco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close. Your code doesn't extract the link URL because it is not the value of the element `<link>` but it is the value of its *attribute* `"href"`.

You can extract the value of the attribute with the following code:

```
type Link struct {
    Href string `xml:"href,attr"`
}
```

And your modified `Entry` type:

```
type Entry struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"entry"`
    Link    Link     `xml:"link"`
    Title   string   `xml:"title"`
}
```

Try your modified app on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/7HRHusXLe2).

Comment: Hey thanks it worked I am newbie to golang would you recommend some sources to learn more ?

Comment: @Shubham For XML parsing and generating check out the package documentation of the [`xml`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/) package. For everything else Go, [golang.org](http://golang.org/) is the main source. For nice readings, check out its [Blog](http://blog.golang.org/) page.

Comment: Thank's I will take note of it.